# Excel comparison of two columns and print value of other column for the matching entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have and excel with the following columns,

```
aaa,123,bbb    
bbb,234,ccc    
ddd,456,avc    
eee,333,aaa
```

I need to compare each element in column A with Column C and for the elements existing on column A and C i need to print the corresponding value in b column.For example in above case the output will be like,

```
aaa,123,bbb,333    
bbb,234,ccc,123    
ddd,456,avc,not present in C    
eee,333,aaa,not present in C
```

Thanks in Advance,
Raghavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this INDEX/MATCH:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),"not present in C")
```

[image]